# Case When + Concatenate from Two Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to concatenate two fields from different tables, based on the results of a case when.  This is what I have so far -

```
Select 
CASE WHEN [Record] = 'Criteria' then (dbo.[Table A].[Field] + ' ' + dbo.[Table B].[Field]) AS 'Name'

Else ' '

INNER JOIN dbo.[Table] ON dbo.[Table].[Field] = dbo.[Table].[Field]

From [Table]
```

But when I run this, I keep getting the error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AS'.

I don't know if my statement is just totally wrong or I have missed something in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that using `+` to concatenating string you will get `NULL` if `tab_a.[Field]` or `tab_b.[Field]` is NULL.

Second use aliases to table names.

```
SELECT
 [Name] = CASE 
             WHEN [Record] = 'Criteria' THEN (tab_a.[Field] + ' ' + tab_b.[Field])
             ELSE ' '
          END
FROM [dbo].[Table A] AS tab_a
JOIN [dbo].[Table B] AS tab_b
  ON tab_a.[Field] = tab_b.[Field]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
CASE WHEN [Record] = 'Criteria' then (dbo.[Table A].[Field] + ' ' + dbo.[Table B].[Field])
Else ' '
end  AS 'Name'
From [Table]
INNER JOIN dbo.[Table] ON dbo.[Table].[Field] = dbo.[Table].[Field]
```

Answer (score 0):

Then problem with your case statement;

```
CASE WHEN [Record] = 'Criteria' then (dbo.[Table A].[Field] + ' ' + dbo.[Table B].[Field])
Else ' ' end AS 'Name'
```